# MySql "WHERE" builder

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I was thinking of implementing a function to "build" the `WHERE` clause in an SQL request like so:

```
"SELECT * FROM table $where"
```

Building `$where` with a cycle that would look like this:

```
$arr=array("Id"=>"1","Time"=>"12:00");
function whereBuild($arr){
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val){
      $result.=$key.'="'.$val.'" AND ';
    }
    $result = substr($result, 0, -5); // removes last AND and spaces
    return $result
}
$where = whereBuild($arr);
```

What do you think? Does it make any sense? Could it be achieved in a simpler/better way?

Thank's!

Comment: You can't use && in a query. Use AND.

Comment: Replace && and perform last "AND" removal by rtrim($where,"AND");

Comment: I've updated the code, thank's for the corrections! Generally speacking, would this be a "good practice"? Or is it "bad coding"? I just came up with it and since I have very little experience, I have no idea of eventual drawback of such a logic..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are always using `AND` in your query you can build an array and [implode](http://php.net/implode) it on return.

```
$arr = array("Id"=>"1","Time"=>"12:00");
function whereBuild($arr){
    $result = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val){
      $result[] = $key.'="'.$val.'"';
    }
    return implode(" AND ", $result);
}
$where = whereBuild($arr);
```

Comment: I've updated the code, with `AND`, but, as mentioned in the comment above, my main question is if this is the right way to do it. Or is it "bad coding"? I just came up with it and since I have very little experience, I have no idea of eventual drawbacks of such a logic..